# react-router-dom conditionally build routes and pass parameters to class based component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building an app with `react-router-dom` that initializes by making AJAX requests and then uses routes to pass parameters to class-based sub components.  I can't figure out how to simultaneously 1) render `<Routes>` conditionally and 2) pass parameters to sub components.

I have a parent level `<RouterApp />` component which is functional, and a conditionally rendered component `<MyClassBasedComponent>`.

In my initial attempt, I set up my code like this:

```
function RouterApp() {
  const preloadData = usePreloadData(); /*custom hook to make an AJAX call*/
  
  /*Conditionally show loader screen or app content*/
  if (!preloadData) {
    return <WelcomeLoader />;
  } else {
    //build routes obj
    const routesObj = {
      "/": () => (props) => <About />,
      "/component/:clientid": (clientID) => <MyClassBasedComponent 
                                             essentialData={preloadData}
                                             clientID={clientID}/>,
    };


    return (
      <Router>
        <HeaderMenu />
          <div className="app-body router-app">
             {useRoutes(routesObj)}
          </div>
      </Router>
    );
    
  }
}
```

This throws a compile error:  `React Hook "useRoutes" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?`

My next attempt was to create a routes object in array-of-dictionaries form:

```
function RouterApp() {
  const preloadData = usePreloadData(); /*custom hook to make an AJAX call*/
  
  /*Conditionally show loader screen or app content*/
  if (!preloadData) {
    return <WelcomeLoader />;
  } else {
    //build routes obj
    
    const routesObj = [
      { path: "/", element: <About /> },
      { path: "/component/:clientid", "element": (clientid) => (<MyClassBasedComponent
                                             essentialData={preloadData}
                                             clientID={clientid}/>) },
      //Various other attempts below
      //{ path: "/component", element: <ClassComponentWithLink/> },
      //{ path: "/component/:clientid", element: (clientid)=><ClassComponentWithLink id={clientid}/> },
      //{ path: "/component/:clientid", element: <ClassComponentWithLink myProp={clientid}/> },
      
    ];
    const MyRoutes = (props) => useRoutes(props.routesObj);


    return (
      <Router>
        <HeaderMenu />
          <div className="app-body router-app">
             <MyRoutes 
                  routesObj = {routesObj}
              />
          </div>
      </Router>
    );
    
  }
}
```

When I use this form and pass a function to "element", `<MyClassBasedComponent />` does not render.

When I use the form `{ path: "/component/:clientid", element: <MyClassBasedComponent /> },`, the component renders, but when I interrogate its props, I don't see the value of `clientid` anywhere.

How can I accomplish this properly?

[Here is the relevant documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useroutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both implementations are incorrect. In `react-router-dom@6` there are no longer any route props (*`history`, `location`, and `match`*) and were replaced by React hooks. Since you are also using a React class component, the hooks can't be used, directly, so you'll need to either convert the class components into function components, or create a wrapper component or custom `withRouter` HOC to access the hooks and pass along/inject the old route props. I won't cover converting a class component into a function component.

- Wrapper example

  Create a wrapper component that uses the `useParams` hook to read the `clientid` route param and render the `MyClassBasedComponent` component.

  ```
    const MyClassBasedComponentWrapper = () => {
      const { clientId } = useParams();
      return (
        <MyClassBasedComponent
          essentialData={preloadData}
          clientID={clientid}
        />
      );
    };
  ```

  Then specify the routes config as per expected.

  ```
  const routesObj = [
    { path: "/", element: <About /> },
    {
      path: "/component/:clientid",
      element: <MyClassBasedComponentWrapper />
    },  
  ];
  ```
- Custom `withRouter` example

  ```
  const withRouter = Component => props => {
    const params = useParams();
    ... use the other hooks here if you need them ...
    return <Component {...props} params={params} />;
  };
  ```

  Decorate the `MyClassBasedComponent` component so it receives `params` as a prop.

  ```
   export default withRouter(MyClassBasedComponent);
  ```

  Then specify the routes config as per expected.

  ```
  const routesObj = [
    { path: "/", element: <About /> },
    {
      path: "/component/:clientid",
      element: <MyClassBasedComponent />
    },  
  ];
  ```

  Inside the `MyClassBasedComponent` component access the `clientId` param from `this.props.params`.

  ```
   `const { clientId } = this.props.params;
  ```

Configuring the `RouterApp` component:

```
const routesObj = [
  { path: "/", element: <About /> },
  {
    path: "/component/:clientid",
    element: <MyClassBasedComponent />
  },  
];

function RouterApp() {
  const preloadData = usePreloadData();
  const routes = useRoutes(routesObj);
  
  return !preloadData
    ? <WelcomeLoader />
    : (
      <Router>
        <HeaderMenu />
        <div className="app-body router-app">
          {routes}
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  };
}
```